# How to determine which combination of substances will give a buffered solution given target pH and Kb of each substances

Tags: titration

> What combination of substances will give a buffered solution that has a pH of 5.05? (Assume each pair of substances is dissolved in 5.0 L of water.) (Kb for NH3 = $1.8 × 10^{–5}$; Kb for C5H5N = $1.7 × 10^{–9}$)
>
> a)1.0 mole NH3 and 1.5 mole NH4Cl
>
> b)1.5 mole NH3 and 1.0 mole NH4Cl
>
> c)1.0 mole C5H5N and 1.5 mole C5H5NHCl
>
> d)1.5 mole C5H5N and 1.0 mole C5H5NHCl

According to my text book it is choice C but I do not understand why and here was my thought process:

---

For starters I change the $K_b$ into $K_a$ to get : $5.6*10^{-10}$ for Ammonia and for the other I got: $5.9*10^{-6}$

It seems to me that this has to do with the Henderson Hasselbach Equation so I set up the following:

$5.05=5.9*10^{-6}+log{\frac{Base}{acid}}$

$5.05=5.9*10^{-10}+log{\frac{Base}{acid}}$

because I already have two substances.

But from here I feel like that wasn't the best route I should take because I got stuck right here and would like some assistance.

Comment: btw please don't down vote because I didn't "show enough thought" Im a beginner chemistry student and I really would like assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Henderson-Hesselbach equation is a good idea. As you want the buffer's pH to be acidic, then using the $\ce{NH3/NH4+}$ buffer is not a good idea, as that would be basic, so we should use the $\ce{C5H5N/C5H5NHCl}$. Then, by Henderson-Hesselbach, we have that $\ce{5.05 = pH = pKa + \log \left(\frac{[C5H5N]}{[C5H5NH+]}\right)}\implies \ce{5.05 - pKa = 5.05 - 5.23 = \log \left(\frac{[C5H5N]}{[C5H5NH+]}\right)} \implies \ce{\frac{[C5H5N]}{[C5H5NH+]} = 10^{-0.18}\implies \frac{[C5H5N]}{[C5H5NH+]} \approx 0.66\approx \frac 23}.$ Thus, we want a buffer solution where the ratio of the base to the acid is approximately 2/3, which answer choice C satisfies.

Comment: I understand everything except why it has to be 2/3 to satisfy the fact that we want 5.05, if I understand ill check your answer!

Comment: @JohnRawls If you use the henderson-hesselbach equation and substitute in known values, then you can solve for the mole ratio of 2/3